# Bootstrap navbar collapses, but won't toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap to try creating a responsive navigation bar.  Whenever I test the site locally (i.e. just opening it up in a browser), then the navigation bar collapses and the button is clickable, which is what I want.  When I put the site online the navigation bar collapses, but the button is not clickable.  I have searched through other similar questions (I know there are many), but cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong.

I also attempted to go through the documentation, with no success.  I would also like to put the button on the left-hand portion of the navigation bar upon collapse, which I can't seem to figure out how to do. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse top-buffer" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Online Trainer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Supplements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sponsored Athletes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exercise Guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: are you using `bootstrap.min.js` ?

Comment: Is this a default installation of bootstrap? I would check to make sure your dependent JS files are loading correctly (jquery.js bootstrap.js etc) If those are loading fine I would check your console for errors.

Comment: <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

both appear before the closing of the body tag.  I have also checked the console for errors and there aren't any.

Comment: Your nav links (.navbar-collapse div) are inside the .navbar-header which shouldn't be, .navbar-header should close before .navbar-collapse starts. This may have nothing to do with your root problem but could be an issue nonetheless. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Okay, I've fixed that and followed the documentation, with the only difference being navbar-inverse.  Still not working.  Any other ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: You should change your CDN references to HTTPS because (for me at least) your CSS isn't loading. Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Like a rookie, I was not including the bootstrap.min.js like I should have been.  I corrected my mistake and now everything is working correctly.